# How can I narrow type parameter that extends sum type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function, say `f`, that accepts an object of `string | SomeClass` and returns an array of objects of the same type as the given argument, that is, if the argument is string then the returned should be `string[]`, otherwise `SomeClass[]`

I think its signature can be writen as ;

```js
function f<T extends string | SomeClass>(x: T): T[]
```

I have an implementation, say `fImpl`, that accepts only `SomeClass` and returns `SomeClass[]`. I will use `fImpl` in `f`. If string is given, the value is passed to `fImpl` and output of `fImpl` is returned after converted to `string[]`. If it is `SomeClass`, the argument and outputs are both passed through.

What I thought, but did not work, was:

```js
function f<T extends string | SomeClass>(x: T): T[] {
  if (typeof x === "string") {
    const ret = fImpl(parseSomeClass(x));
    return ret.map((r) => r.toString()); // (1)
  } else {
    return fImpl(x); // (2)
  }
}
```

A compiler says that

```
Type string[] is not assignable to type 'T[]'
```

and

```
Type SomeClass[] is not assignable to type 'T[]'
```

As far as I understand, the compiler keeps to regard `x` to be of type `T` even in the `if` and `else` clause where `x` must be `string` and `SomeClass` in each. How can I teach it that the type of `x` is narrowed there.

Comment: I suspect you want overloads, not generics. https://tsplay.dev/WK90zN But without a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is hard to advise more.

Comment: @AlexWayne thank you for comment and example code. I'm sorry for my lack of complete example. Anyway, I understood your idea and solved my situation.